# Не работает копирование драйвера в inf

Tags: драйвер, setup

Пишу установщик драйвера для windows 8.1.
Драйвер и inf находятся в одном каталоге.

**DriverMinGW.Inf:**

```
; DriverMinGW.Inf
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=Unknown
Provider=%SKBIS%
DriverVer=26/07/2017,0.0.0.2

[Manufacturer]
%MFGNAME%=DeviceList,ntamd64    

[DestinationDirs]
DriverCopyFiles=10,System32\Drivers ; путь для копирования драйвера под Windows NT

[SourceDisksNames.ntamd64]
1="DriverMinGW build directory",,, 

[SourceDisksFiles.ntamd64]
DriverMinGW.sys=1,, ; путь, где находится версия драйвера под Windows NT
; в нашем случае обе версии драйверов, конечно, одинаковые

[DeviceList.ntamd64]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall,*UUU\AAAA

[DriverInstall.ntamd64]
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles

[DriverCopyFiles]
DriverMinGW.sys,,,2

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.Services]
AddService=DriverMinGW,2,DriverService

[DriverService]
DisplayName = %DriverMinGW.ServiceName%
ServiceType = %SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER%
StartType = %SERVICE_DEMAND_START%
ErrorControl = %SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL%
ServiceBinary = %10%\System32\Drivers\DriverMinGW.sys

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.hw]
AddReg=DriverHwAddReg

[DriverHwAddReg]
HKR,,DriverMinGWInfo,,""

; Строки
[Strings]
DriverMinGW.ServiceName="DriverMinGW"
MFGNAME="SKBIS"
ProviderDriverMinGW="Napisanie draiverov v podrobnostjah №4"
DESCRIPTION="DriverMinGW driver: checked build"

DriverMinGW.ServiceName="DriverMinGW NTDDK driver (V.001)"

SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE=0x00000002
COPYFLG_NOSKIP=2 
SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER=1
SERVICE_AUTO_START=2
SERVICE_DEMAND_START=3 
SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL=1
```

В результате установки открывается такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего выходит окно с успешным завершением операции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В папку C:\Windows\System32\drivers драйвер не копируется!**

Зато появляется копия драйвера и установщика в папке **C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository**

Что бы я не делал копирования не происходит. Объясните где я ошибся?

Comment: А вот странные вопрос задам: система x64? Чем смотрите содержимое C:\Windows\System32\drivers?

Comment: Действительно странный вопрос. да x64. Смотрю explorer.exe

Comment: В 64-битной винде 32-битный софт может видеть в ФС не то, что по тому же пути увидит 64-битный. Но у вас, выходит, не эта проблема.

Comment: Да. По факту у меня установщик не копирует файлы вообще. Даже если я просто пишу копирование -1 по полному пути. Все равно не работает

Comment: При этом если я пишу за место DriverInstall.ntamd64 DefaultInstall то файл копируется но драйвер не запускается.

Comment: "установщик не копирует файлы вообще" - а что за установщик?

Comment: Системный установщик inf. как он называется я и понятия не имею